# Java: Execute one more command after the first command that i ran on linux/win m/c

Tags: java

I have a command that i execute from my Java program like:-

```
String command="C:\\my\\abc.bat";
Process process = null;
try {           
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command); 
process.waitFor();
```

now this command when ran from the command line asks for a password. So would it here. How can i write out the password to this.

Example:-
1) run the command.
2) Enter the password:-

i am done with the first step. How can i enter the password after its execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it using:-

```
String command="C:\\my\\abc.bat";
Process process = null;
try {           
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command); 
 OutputStream out=process.getOutputStream();
 out.write("mypass".getBytes());
 out.flush();
```

Also removed out the **`waitFor()`** causing the stream to close.

Answer (score 1):

Use this syntax to pass the password as a CLI parameter:

```
String password = "your password"
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"C:\\my\\abc.bat", password});
```

Or, if your program is interactive, use [`getOutputStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getOutputStream()) to get an output stream to which write the password. Example:

```
String password = "your password"
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(process.getOutputStream());
writer.println(password);
writer.close();
```

Note that this is simplified example, you'll have to manage the exception appropriately.

Comment: tried it.. Doesn't work :(.. Its not throwing an exception but the a ticket was supposed to be generated after this. Which is not comming

Comment: the password is the only data that is required from the external process? do you have any ways to dump the input?

Comment: yes, the password is the only thing. One more thing i observed here was when i add a getInputStrem to view if its showing "enter password". Even this string is not coming up. Strange

Comment: Yes, cause the command takes an argument along with it. After the .bat its password .. So its like "C:\\my\\abc.bat password".. If i spell password incorrect i get the error message printed in my inputstream

Comment: From your comment I understand that you need a parameter. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: No the password here is not the actual password. Its the mechanism i opted to authenticate. It will ask the password after the execution of my command

Comment: C:\\my\\abc.bat HereWePasstheAuthticationMethod

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57321/discussion-between-mxb-and-dennis).